# Restore original selection in datagrid after calling SelectAllCells()

Tags: wpf, datagrid, code-behind

I have a right-click context menu for my DataGrid control. One of its menu items is 'Copy All'. When user clicks 'Copy All' it should copy all datagrid content to clipboard so user can paste it into Excel.

I'm looking at ApplicationCommands.Copy command but seems like it works only with **selected items**. So I'm trying to select all cells in my command handler, execute Copy command and then unselect all cells:

```
SelectAllCells();
ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, this);
UnselectAllCells();
```

But what if user selected several rows (for example rows 1,3 and 5) and clicked 'Copy All'. In this case I should restore his selection after selecting all cells and executing Copy command. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little fiddly, but it can be done.
The basic premise is to take a note of what you have selected before you select everything; and then reselect those records after the copy.

Not the ToList() after the Distinct() is important.  It will not work without this because of LINQ's deferred execution.

I also added in code to disable dispatcher processing.  This will prevent messages being processed on the dispatcher (i.e. will stop the screen trying to redraw while the programmatic manipulation is happening)

```
        var selectionMode = dg.SelectionMode;
        var token = Application.Current.Dispatcher.DisableProcessing();

        var selectedItems = dg.SelectedCells.Select(x => x.Item).Distinct().ToList();

        try
        {
            dg.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
            dg.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;
            dg.SelectAll();
            ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dg);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            dg.SelectionMode = selectionMode;
            dg.UnselectAll();

            foreach (var selectedItem in selectedItems)
            {
                dg.SelectedItems.Add(selectedItem);

                var row = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedItem) as DataGridRow;

                if (row != null)
                {
                    DataGridCell cell = GetCell(dg, row, 0);

                    if (cell != null)
                    {
                        cell.Focus();
                    }
                }
            }

            token.Dispose();
        }
```

dg is the name of the DataGrid.

The code for the static GetCell method can be found on this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21202.wpf-programmatically-selecting-and-focusing-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid.aspx).

Comment: thanks! It works. Probably one remark I have. I will get InvalidOperationException (Can only change SelectedItems collection in multiple selection modes. Use SelectedItem in single select modes.) in line dg.SelectedItems.Add(selectedItem) if my DataGrid has SelectionMode set to Single. So I think I should restore original SelectionMode after foreach loop to avoid this Exception.

Comment: yes, you're right.  glad it works - would you mind accepting the answer if you're happy with it?